# LateInitializationError: Field 'screenWidth' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter

I am developing a mobile flutter application. I created a config myself to be able to use it on every page, but LateInitializationError: Field 'screenWidth' has not been initialized. I'm getting the error I need help.The question has been shared before, but there is no answer, so I wanted to ask it again.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SizeConfig {
  static late MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static late double screenWidth;
  static late double screenHeight;
  static double? defaultSize;
  static Orientation? orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
  }
}

// Get the proportionate height as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenHeight(double inputHeight) {
  double screenHeight = SizeConfig.screenHeight;
  // 812 is the layout height that designer use
  return (inputHeight / 812.0) * screenHeight;
}

// Get the proportionate height as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenWidth(double inputWidth) {
  double screenWidth = SizeConfig.screenWidth;
  // 375 is the layout width that designer use
  return (inputWidth / 375.0) * screenWidth;
}
```

static? double screenWidth; I did it like this, but this time I'm getting the Null check operator used on a null value error.

Comment: `late` means : you promise to the flutter that before using `SizeConfig()` the value fro all variable delcare with `late`, has been initialized.  so if you use it before initialize, it will throw error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late fields must be initialized before use, in your case you might have forgotten to call the `init` method before accessing the fields. So, make sure to call the `init` method before accessing the fields in thae class `SizeConfig`.